# JButton not sending action command

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on a school project and I'm having a dickens of a time trying to get the JButton to do..well.. anything! this is my code, I don't know how important the other .java files are.

I started with a simple code that worked but after adding and editing it can't seem to update the text exactly how I want it.

```
    <removed>
```

var1, var2, etc. that are being passed in are stored as such..

they are all in another .java file

the Function.fun

```
    <removed>
```

Comment: We need the code for `finalproject2.Function` so we can see what `fun.process` does. Presumably `process` does not update your variables.

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay...

1. Don't rely on `static`, it's not going to help you and will create a whole lot of new issues which will be difficult to solve
2. The main problem is, your code is generating a `NumberFormatException` - `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "javax.swing.JSpinner[,8,6,109x26,invalid,layout=com.apple.laf.AquaSpinnerUI$SpinnerLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777536,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]"`

So, based on the exception, it's obvious that `Double.parseDouble` isn't getting the value it excpects

So, having a deeper look at your code...

```
if (jspValue1.getValue() instanceof Double) {
    s = jspValue1.toString();
    d = Double.parseDouble(s);
    return d;
} else {
    return 0.00;
}
```

You're passing the result of `jspValue.toString` to `Double.parseDouble`, but he fact is, it's just not required.

You've already determined that the value from the `JSpinner` is a double, so you on;y need to cast it...

```
double value = 0.00d;
if (jspValue1.getValue() instanceof Double) {
    value = (Double)jspValue1.getValue();
}
return value;
```

Comment: Wow! You guys rock, Thank You! I'm having one last problem and I think after that I'll be 100%!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm passing in the `JRadioButtons` into the `Function.fun.process` correctly, it doesn't seem to change any of the values. I even added an else at the end of process that sets the `bankAccount.balance` to 0 but I still don't see it updating 
-
(after making the changes you recommended it worked and changed the first line to "Farts!" as well as getting a readout in the `System.out` tray (not sure what to call it) so I know it is calling the action but not the function)

Comment: You never change the state of `jrbWith`

Comment: wouldn't `JRadioButton jrbWithdraw = new JRadioButton("Withdraw", jrbWith);` cause it to change jrbWith on press?

Comment: No, all it does is sets the initial state

Comment: Got it! You rock! thank you very much for all your help, is there a +1 system or a way of marking your answer as the best answer and like closing the question?

Comment: Typically, you can upvote the question by clicking the "up" arrow if it helped and/or you can click the grayed out tick to accept the answer, check out the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for more details